# Convergence of a Bernoulli sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I am facing a big chalenge to formalize the answer. Thinking all day.
Any help? Hint?

Consider $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$,$X_{3}$,$X_{4}$,$X_{5}$,... i.i.d Bernoulli(i.e $P(X_{i}=1)=p),P(X_{i}=0)=1-p)$:

i) Does $Y_{n} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$. $\overline{Y_{n}} = \sum \frac{Y_{n}}{n}$ converges to a constant? Which one? Almost surely or just in probability?

ii) Does $W_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$. $\overline{W_{n}} = \sum \frac{W_{n}}{n}$ converges to a constant? Which one? Almost surely or just in probability?

iii) Does $Z_{n} =\prod_{i=n-1}^{n} X_{i}$. $\overline{Z_{n}} = \sum \frac{Z_{n}}{n}$ converges to a constant? Which one? Almost surely or just in probability?

Comment: Care to share some of your thoughts?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. But I dont know how to formalize then. I belive that the sequence $\overline{Y_{n}}$ converges to 0. Because somehow $X_{i}$ will take the 0 value with probability $p$. $W_{n}$ will converge for a constant tht would be $E(X_{i))}$. The third one Iam stil thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: I will provide some answers and leave the rest to you. Since $P(X_n=1 \forall n)=0$ (assuming $0<p<1$) we see that $Y_n=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, with probability $1$. This implies that $\sum \frac {Y_n} n$ converges almost surely. The sum is not a constant.

By Strong Law $\frac {W_n} n \to p$ almost surely. A series cannot converge unless its general term tends to $0$. SO the second series neither converges almost surely nor does it converge in probability.

Comment: many, many thanks!. One question, why you assume that $P(X_{n}=1)=0$? After this I understand what will come later with $Y_{n} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: $P(X_n=1 \text {for} \, 1\leq n \leq N)=p^{N}$. Since $p <1$ this probability tends to $0$, so $P(X_n=1 \forall n)=0$.